# In AngularJS = "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, promise

Help!

I'm relatively new to AngualarJS -- be kind!
I have a function in a service ...

```
function getVersion() {
    return $http.get('package.json').then(function success(response) {
            if (!utilsService.isNullOrUndefined(response.data.version)) {
                return response.data.version;  // this returns what is expected
            } else {
                return 'x.x.x';
            }
        }, function error(response) {
            return 'x.x.x';
        }
    );
}
```

In my controller I'm trying to call the service ... I keep getting "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
When I step through the service, its what I expect.

The controller function(s)...

```
 var vm = this;
 vm.version =  '-.-.-';
 activate();
 function activate() {
     logger.info('Activated Login View');
     loginService.getVersion().then(function(data) {
         vm.version = data.version;
     });        
 }  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Your `utilsService.isNullOrUndefined(response.data.version)` is just `response.data.version == null`.

Comment: Thanks -- I created a function to check for null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getVersion()` function doesn't return anything, therefore the return value is `undefined`. You should properly return your promise:

```
return $http.get('package.json').then(function success(response) {
```

Comment: Thanks ... but I still don't get it.  How do I "properly return" the promise?

Comment: Yes you did -- sorry, I missed the 'return' ... the rest of the code as the same as mine.  Again, thank you.

Comment: I'm still missing something.  In getVersion(), I am using `code`return $http.get('package.json').then(function success(response) { `code` and it is returning what I expect.  But in the controller 'data.version is undefined'